# How to use search and update cursor on two tables to update values?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I would like to read the values from the `company` field of `linefc`, if the values from this field in `table` then a the `WORSTOFFENDER` field should be updated with the value YES, if it is not, then NO.  What needs to be added to complete this?

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(linefc,["Company"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        linecur =row[0]

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table,["DAMAGING_PARTY"]) as tablecursor:
    for tablerow in tablecursor:
        tablecur =  tablerow[0]


print "DONE"
```

Comment: What table has the field "worst offender?"?

Comment: linefc has the WorstOffender field

Comment: does the feature class (company) and table (table) have a field with a shared key?

Comment: yes, `company` for the fc, and `damaging_party` for the table

Comment: This needs to be done by loading the records in the first table to a dictionary with the shared key value being the key of the dictionary.  Then use an update cursor to lookup the share key and if it is in the dictionary you would set the worstoffender value to "YES" and otherwise to "NO".  The second table has to include both the DAMAGING_PARTY field and the WORSTOFFENDER field in the field list of the update cursor to work. See my blog on this topic here:  https://geonet.esri.com/blogs/richard_fairhurst/2014/11/08/turbo-charging-data-manipulation-with-python-cursors-and-dictionaries

Comment: I am calculating "WORSTOFFENDER" for the feature class, COMPANY and DAMAGING_PARTY is the shared key.

Comment: There are many similar existing Q&As on this site that should help you but the first thing to modify in your code snippet will be to incorporate an `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read all the values from `DAMAGING_PARTY` from the table into a python set, and then with an Update Cursor check if the `COMPANY` value exists in that set, and if it does set the `WORSTOFFENDER` to `YES` otherwise set it to `NO`

```
damagingParty = set()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ["DAMAGING_PARTY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        damagingParty.add(row[0])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(linefc, ["Company", "WORSTOFFENDER"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in damagingParty:
            row[1] = "YES"
        else:
            row[1] = "NO"
        cursor.updateRow(row)

print "DONE"
```

Comment: Even more concise: `damaging_party = set(row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, ["DAMAGING_PARTY"]))`

Answer (score 2):

I would just load the first cursor into its own global list:

```
companyList = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(linefc,["Company"]) as cursor:
    companyList = [row for row in cursor]
```

Then I would check for inclusion in this list and use an update cursor to update the values:

```
tableFieldList = ['DAMAGING_PARTY', 'WORSTOFFENDER']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, tableFieldList) as tablecursor:
    for tablerow in tablecursor:
        if tablerow[0] in companyList:
            tablerow[1] = 'YES'
        else:
            tablerow[1] = 'NO'
        cursor.updateRow(tablerow)
```

Comment: `table` does not contain the field `WORSTOFFENDER`.  I would like to update the `WORSTOFFENDER` field to yes or no in the feature class based on if the value for `DAMAGING_PARTY` is in the table.

Comment: Oh that wasn't super clear.  The general idea still applies though - load one of the tables single field into a list, then check for inclusion with the other using an update cursor.